# How to create litlle glow outside a button

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm actually trying to create a little outer glow like this picture outside a button on windows phone 8.

[image]

Do you know a way to reproduce that ?

- A = without glow
- B = with glow (target)

(it is actually a Photoshop Vision)

If it's possible to achieve that with code it's better because, all my button are actually created by code.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: First, glow effect doesn't suit Metro design. Second, you can export it from Photoshop and then use it in app. There is no easy way to create it.

Comment: WPF supports Effect Property. which isn't supported in windows phone

Comment: @ToniPetrina Thanks. I'm aware about the Metro design, and the example i show before, is an example not the final design. I'm not sure to understand how to export it from PS and use it in the App ? Note that the background image will be used with another image. 
The glow is only needed when clicking on the button.

Comment: Glow should be exported as a PNG with transparency. You would then have to completely restyle button to add a picture background (the glow effect) and show it only when the visual state is "Pressed".

Comment: I'd suggest talking with your UI designer about the design philosophy of WP8 apps and some of the tchnology. If you use bitmaps, you'll defeat the strengths of the adaptive resizing and layout that is available. If your button changes width due to a localized string being even a single pixel wider, you'd need to use a different "glow" bitmap.

Comment: Thanks @WiredPrairie . I'm agree with you about using bitmaps. That's not the solution I want to target. That's why I would like to create this kind of glow effect outside the button.
Ensure that's not a WP8 Application, it'a game and it didnt follow the Metre design. Otherwise, concerning the adaptative design, I'm agree with you and that's why I would like to achevieve that using code only.

Comment: There are no "effects" on WP8 that would provide the look you're going for. You might be able to create something by drawing and sizing a glow on a canvas and placing it behind the button. It's not a small amount of code though, and would be well beyond a normal sized StackOverflow answer.